# undefined reference to ' ' (ОШИБКА КОМПОНОВКИ)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, undefined-reference

хочу показать мою проблему на примере 3-ёх мини-файлов: pr1.h pr2.cpp main.cpp.
Я пересмотрел множество похожих вопросов с аналогичной проблемой, но так и не смог исправить ошибку.

```
// pr1.h int 
   f(int a);

// pr2.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "pr1.h"

int f(int a)
{
    return a;
}

// main.cpp
#include "pr1.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   int a = f(5);
   cout << a << endl;
}
```

Использую VS Code на Linux Mint, при отладке терминал выводит следующее:

> Executing task: /usr/bin/g++ -g '/home/nik/Документы/Test /main.cpp' -o '/home/nik/Документы/Test /main' main':
>   /home/nik/Документы/Test /main.cpp:8: undefined reference tof(int)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Пробовал вбивать в терминал команду "g++ -o pr1 pr2.cpp main.cpp" - никакой реакции.

Прошу Вашей помощи.

Comment: Что означает "никакой реакции"? Что при этом говорит компилятор? В первом случае у вас явно не подключенный файл `pr2.cpp`, в котором определена функция `f`...

Comment: Не при отладке (для отладки нужно хотя бы скомпилировать прогу), а при линковке.

Comment: @Harry Когда я использую встроенный в vs code компилятор он выводит то, что приведено в вопросе,
когда вбиваю в терминал команду "g++ -o pr1 pr2.cpp main.cpp" - терминал просто перебрасывает на пустую строку, т.е. nik@nik-TM1701:~$ , иными словами ничего не происходит явно
У меня слинковалась программа, когда я добавил в main.cpp #include pr2.cpp , хотя во всех примерах в инете при добавлении заголовочного файла достаточно "файл.h", т.е. объявление функции, тогда как её реализация прописывается в cpp-файле

Comment: А что-то должно происходить? `./a.out`?